# Set fragment order preference

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm creating a part of my app where I have a main activity where I added two fragments. They're two identical ScrollViews where I'm just putting 
 different text. I want to make a preference between them.

So my idea is:
We have a Fragment A that will always show up first while Fragment B is not visible in screen. I would like to put a button to swap into both fragments whenever the user wants.

So, which is the best way to develop this idea? I'm posting some code related to my Fragment A:

Main Fragment Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:id="@+id/listaMain">
    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.example.comprasapp.Lists.ListsFragments.ListViewSolo"
              android:id="@+id/scrollSoloList"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment A:

```
<ScrollView
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/scrollSoloList"
             android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textListaSolo" tools:targetApi="o"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Fragment A controller class:

```
class ListViewSolo : Fragment(){
    var facade = Facade()
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_solo, container, true)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textListaSolo)?.autoSizeMaxTextSize
        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textListaSolo)?.text = (facade.setListSolo())//I'm just setting the text on my TextView here
    }
    companion object{
        // Aqui simplemente estás creando un objeto ListViewSolo por si en algun momento tienes que utilizarlo

        fun newInstance(): ListViewSolo {
            return ListViewSolo()
        }
    }

}
```

If I can clearify something just ask it, thank you.

Comment: You probably want a `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what don't you use `ViewPager` , its main purpose of use is to achieve you criteria .

it can also give you great sliding [animation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_screenslide.mp4) between your fragment with an easy [implementation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) .

please check [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter) tutorial to learn how to implement `ViewPager` in your app

Answer (score 1):

You can use a container to switch between your fragments,

Main Fragment Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:id="@+id/listaMain">

            <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And for switching between your fragments you can use this wherever you want :

```
val fragment = ListViewSolo() // your fragment instance

val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    add.commit()
```